# Invalid String Format

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a gridview that contains string value but was number/integer

> e.g: "1", "10"

problem was I also have data that was `-` on it and since its a char it cannot convert to integer.

here is a line of my lambda:

```
var gp_lt = gridData.Where(n => n.Profit != "-" && Convert.ToInt32(n.Profit) >= 0).Select(o => new { o.Profit });
double grossprofit_LT = gp_lt.Sum(o => Convert.ToDouble(o.Profit));
```

`Profit = number` but was `string` ...

value of `-` was not `0` ... just want to exclude all those who has `-` and convert the profit to `int`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GrantWinney no, just data with "-" value so i cant use .contains reason why negative nums also contains "-"

Comment: no, positive nums only @GrantWinney

Comment: @GrantWinney it doesnt compile ... when i try to run it by breakpoint and use try catch it says Invalid String Format

Comment: If you can debug your program then it means it **does** compile.

Comment: it has no output in Console either :/

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
double grossprofit_LT = gridData.Select(x =>
        {
            var styles = NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
            if (x.Profit.StartsWith("-"))
                return (double?) double.Parse(x, styles);

            if (x.Profit.Contains('.'))
                return (double?) double.Parse(x,styles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var seperator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;

            if (x.Profit.Contains(',') && seperator == ",") 
               return (double?) double.Parse(x, styles);

            return null;
        }).Where(x => x.HasValue).Sum(x => x.Value);
```

This will handle all values like:

```
-3
-2.23
1,15
```

And return you sum of them.If you don't want to include negative numbers just remove the first condition. `if (x.Profit.StartsWith("-"))`

**UPDATE:** If you want to make it simpler, and your values doesn't contain any *dot* or *comma*, you can just use

```
gridData.Where(x => !x.Profit.Contains("-"))
        .Select(x => double.Parse(x.Profit.Trim())
        .Sum();
```

You are comparing `Profit` with `-` in your code.But probably some of your values are starts with `-`  so you are getting the format exception.Use `Contains`  or `StartsWith` method instead.

Comment: whats with the "." and ","

Comment: using .Contains was ok for this condition but i have other lambdas that searching for negative numbers so i cant use .Contains("-") i think ... i just want to exclude the string with exact "-" (dash) value not negative

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from the fact that you have this line in your first statement:

```
Convert.ToInt32(n.Profit)
```

That will throw an exception if the string you're trying to convert is not actually an integer. Since you're apparently dealing with profits, you've most likely got decimals.

Replace the above with this, and the code you have should work:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(n.Profit)
```

*(I'd recommend using* `Decimal` *instead of* `Double` [*when dealing with money*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when).)

Comment: converting it toDecimal seems work on this condition ... ill just try it on my other lambda and if it works ill accept this answer